# Storing postorder sequence in array

Tags: java

In the code below, the nodes of a postorder tree traversal is always printed
I m wondering if there is a way to store these nodes in the postorder sequence in an array
Do i have to do the traversal in a iterative way?

```
public static void postOrder(TreeNode root) {
  if (root != null) {
    postOrder(root.left);
    postOrder(root.right);
    System.out.print(root.item + "  ");
  } else {
    return;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass a List along with that method. Untested pseudo-ish code:

```
class Tree {

    private TreeNode root;

    // ...

    public List<TreeNode> postOrder() {
        List<TreeNode> nodes = new ArrayList<TreeNode>();  
        fillList(root, nodes);
        return nodes;
    }

    private void fillList(TreeNode node, List<TreeNode> nodeList) { // private!
        if(node != null) {
            fillList(node.left, nodeList);
            fillList(node.right, nodeList);
            nodeList.add(node);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Each recursive call to `postOrder()` from `fillList()` will build up a new node list, each containing no more than one item.

Comment: I forgot to rename the methods... The whole thing wouldn't have compiled in a long shot: I called `postOrder(TreeNode)`, which didn't even exist and forgot to pass the `nodeList` in the recursive call. Ah well, hence my remark: *pseudo-ish*! :)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a list instead of an array. That way you don't need to worry about the size of your tree. (Using an array you should first count the nodes in your tree, which would practically require another full traversal.) Storing the tree nodes themselves is achieved by this method:

```
public static void postOrder(TreeNode root, List<TreeNode> list) {

    if (root != null) {
        postOrder(root.left, list);
        postOrder(root.right, list);
        list.add(root);
    } else {
        return;
    }
}
```

If you want to store only the items (supposing their type is `TreeNodeItem`):

```
public static void postOrder(TreeNode root, List<TreeNodeItem> list) {

    if (root != null) {
        postOrder(root.left, list);
        postOrder(root.right, list);
        list.add(root.item);
    } else {
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to pass `list` down through each recursive call of `postOrder()`.

Answer (score 0):

The need to create the final array is ugly, but here's a mock-up, including a potential definition of type `TreeNode`:

```
final class TreeAccumulator
{
  public static final class TreeNode<T>
  {
    public TreeNode(T item,
                    TreeNode<? extends T> left,
                    TreeNode<? extends T> right) {
      this.item = item;
      this.left = left;
      this.right = right;
    }

    public final T item;
    public final TreeNode<? extends T> left;
    public final TreeNode<? extends T> right;
  }


  public static <T, C extends Collection<T>>
  C postOrder(TreeNode<? extends T> root, C acc)
  {
    if (null == root)
      return acc;

    final C result = postOrder(root.right,
                               postOrder(root.left, acc));
    result.add(root.item);
    return result;
  }


  @SuppressWarnings({"unchecked"})
  public static <T> T[] postOrder(TreeNode<? extends T> root,
                                  Class<T> c)
  {
    final Collection<T> acc = postOrder(root, new LinkedList<T>());
    return acc.toArray((T[])Array.newInstance(c, acc.size()));
  }
}
```

If you knew more about the potential size of the tree ahead of time, you could collect into a pre-allocated `ArrayList` -- or even a primitive array -- more easily.